# resigter for remote notifications causing crash in appDelegate iOS Parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

my app keeps crashing due to this line here `[application registerForRemoteNotifications];` and i can only place it in the position below for it to work. push notes do not send as i have not placed it in the right position.

```
if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
        UIUserNotificationSettings *notificationSettings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories:nil];

        [application registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
    } else {
        UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:notificationTypes];

        [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
    }
```

please help me register the notification so the device gets them on Parse it says pushes sent. any ideas?

Please see crash message

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't use nil for keys or values on PFObject. Use NSNull for values.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x184474f5c 0x198f77f80 0x184474ea4 0x1000f0280 0x1000f4770 0x1001448bc 0x1000ac644 0x1002f1d70 0x1002f1d30 0x1002f7780 0x18442c258 0x18442a0c0 0x184358dc0 0x18f4ac088 0x189a32f60 0x1000ad2c4 0x1997a28b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)




NSNull for values."
0x1000f0278 <+128>: nop    
0x1000f027c <+132>: bl     0x100153e10               ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x1000f0280 <+136>: nop                            //thread 1:signal sigabrt
0x1000f0284 <+140>: ldr    x0, #766268               ; (void *)0x00000001a01f8798: NSString
0x1000f0288 <+144>: nop    
0x1000f028c <+148>: nop    
0x1000f0290 <+152>: ldr    x23, #752712              ; "class"
0x1000f0294 <+156>: mov    x1, x23
0x1000f0298 <+160>: bl     0x100153e10               ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x1000f029c <+164>: mov    x2, x0
0x1000f02a0 <+168>: nop    
0x1000f02a4 <+172>: nop    
0x1000f02a8 <+176>: ldr    x24, #752696              ; "isKindOfClass:"
0x1000f02ac <+180>: mov    x0, x20
0x1000f02b0 <+184>: mov    x1, x24
0x1000f02b4 <+188>: bl     0x100153e10               ; symbol stub for: objc_msgSend
0x1000f02b8 <+192>: tbnz   w0, #0, 0x1000f02e8       ; <+240> at PFObject.m:1918
0x1000f02bc <+196>: nop    
0x1000f02c0 <+200>: ldr    x0, #767680               ; (void *)0x00000001a01ee600: NSException
0x1000f02c4 <+204>: nop    
0x1000f02c8 <+208>: ldr    x8, #572792               ; (void *)0x000000019bde5500:
```

I think this line is null `[currentInstallation setObject:[PFUser currentUser].objectId forKey:@"userId"];`  when i comment it out it works fine.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId] forKey:@"userId"];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

how can i fix it?

Thanks,

Comment: What is the crash message?

Comment: @Paulw11 please see question edit

Comment: There are a few likely duplicates - all seem to be to do with setting the current user into your PFInstallation when PFuser.currentUser is nil because you haven't logged in yet.  When your app crashes look up the stack trace to see which line of your code was the problem, or post more code from your AppDelegate, `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` in particular

Comment: Just saw your edit  - You need to check if `PFUser currentUser` is nil and don't add it to the installation object if it is

Comment: @Paulw11 it is nil when i comment it out the app works fine. but i need it so push notifications get sent to user. i have added these lines to log in and sign up though `[[PFInstallation currentInstallation] setObject:[PFUser currentUser].objectId forKey:@"userId"];
                                                [[PFInstallation currentInstallation] saveInBackground];`

Comment: See the working code in the duplicate question - Also, once someone has logged in to your app you will need to update the `PFInstallation` object and re-save it

Comment: `[[PFInstallation currentInstallation] setObject:[PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"userId"]; saveInBackGround` in your post-login code.